# SSH: remote switch user and execute command under this new user

Tags: ssh, sudo, remote-access, root, su

I am able to connect to remote machine using public/private keys (without password) as user `wakatana`. On remote machine I am able to issue: `sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root` then I type root's password and I get root's permissions. Now I would like to "semi-automate" this process. By semi-automation I mean that I will still need pass root's password but also I will be able to pass another commands which will be executed under root permissions e.g. `cat /etc/shadow`

I have tried following command: `ssh -t targetmachine "sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root; cat /etc/shadow"` but this gives me the interactive root's prompt (after I type the password), and I was able to use the remote machine as if I was logged as root. Only after pressing `ctrl+d` it seems that it tries to open `/etc/shadow` because I get the message:

```
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
Connection to targetmachine closed.
```

What I need is to somehow pass the `cat /etc/shadow` command to `rootsh`. But the problem is that I am not able to `soduo` any other command than `/usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root`

For example when I tried `sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root -- cat /etc/shadow` I get the:

```
Sorry, user wakatana is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root -- cat /etc/shadow' as root on targetmachine.
```

To sum it up, what I need is

1. access the target machine:
2. switch user to root on remote server (type password)
3. execute command under this switched user
4. close connection to remote server

Please note that I am not allowed to:

1. edit sudoers file
2. adding public/private keys to root
3. allowing direct root login

Thank you

**EDIT:**

also I have tried suggested:

```
echo date | sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root
```

but it returns:

```
no tty/pty on stdin: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

Most shells will read from *standard input* even if it isn't a keyboard.
See if this works on `targetmachine`:

```
$ echo date | sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root
[sudo] password for you: 
Mon Oct 14 13:29:09 EDT 2013
```

If so, you can see if using *stdin* works over ssh:

```
$ echo 'date ; whoami ; cat /etc/shadow' | ssh -t targetmachine 'sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root'
```

Or maybe send the commands directly into the remote `sudo`:

```
$ ssh -t targetmachine "echo 'date ; whoami ; cat /etc/shadow' | sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root"
```

Be careful to get the single/double quotes nested correctly.
(My tests show that `sudo` doesn't work in the above examples because
it can't read my local *tty* to get a password.)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

The absolutely least painful solution is to add your account to `sudoers` on the remote machine without a password, and then probably with a restriction as to which commands exactly you are allowed to execute as a privileged user without a password.

The immediate problem with your first attempt is that your command will start an interactive shell, and *then* run the command only after you quit that shell.

With or without making the command passwordless, the command you want to execute is

```
ssh -t targetmachine "sudo /usr/bin/rootsh cat /etc/shadow"
```

The `-i` and `-u root` options seem superfluous in this example.

If you are not allowed to run this command via `rootsh` there is no way really to solve your problem with the information you have provided.

The "no tty" problem happens because standard input is redirected. That means you cannot *both* pipe in a command and have it prompt for your password interactively. You might want to experiment with adding a `-t` option to `ssh` (or more than one!) but I would not hold my hopes too high.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s an example command that you can use to append a line to a file on a remote machine:

```
ssh -t user@remote "sudo sh -c 'echo \"your line here\" >> /path/to/your/file'"
```

Code above is what I found [here](https://cloudscoop.net/how-to-append-a-line-to-a-file-on-a-remote-machine/) and it worked for me.

Comment: This bypasses `rootsh` which presumably is important in the OP's use case.